Failed building wheel for cchardet when installing twint module
8
I got an error when installing twint module involving cchardet. I have already installed that package but I am still getting this error. Please help me find a solution. Here is the the full error message:
Building wheels for collected packages: cchardet
  Building wheel for cchardet (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      cythonize: ['src/cchardet\\_cchardet.pyx']
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\cchardet
      copying src\cchardet\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\cchardet
      copying src\cchardet\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\cchardet
      running build_ext
      building 'cchardet._cchardet' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\cchardet
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\ext
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\ext\uchardet
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\ext\uchardet\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\ext\uchardet\src\LangModels
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ext/uchardet/src "-IC:\Users\Felipe Ojalvo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include" "-IC:\Users\Felipe Ojalvo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpsrc/cchardet\_cchardet.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src/cchardet\_cchardet.obj
      _cchardet.cpp
      C:\Users\Felipe Ojalvo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\pyconfig.h(230): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cchardet
  Running setup.py clean for cchardet
Failed to build cchardet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cchardet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have tried installing microsoft buildtools 2022, but the error persists.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22basetsd.h+No+such+file+or+directory%22
